# locals.pretty in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send pretty html using Express 4. How can I user `app.locals.pretty` with Express 4? Old syntan doesn't work:

`app.locals.pretty = true;`

Whole block of code:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1339);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(morgan());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser('123'));

app.use(session({
    secret: '123',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: SessionStore
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the whole codeblock where you configure your app? `pretty:true` is actually a Jade option, and there's no mention of having this changed in 4.x.

Comment: @raina77ow, updated my question. I don't use Jade's `render` function, I just use `res.send()` to send JSON which I using in my API.

Comment: It's actually Express's `render` function, but that's nitpicking. `res.send()` doesn't use locals - only `res.render()`. `send` just sends whatever data you give it.

Comment: @Scimonster so how can I send pretty json? I used Express 3 and everything worked fine, but after update to Express 4 it doesn't work

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For pretty printing json, you can set the number indented spaces which should turn on pretty printing:

```
app.set('json spaces', 2);
```

Then just do:

```
res.json({ foo: 'bar', baz: 1234567890 });
```

Similarly you can `app.set('json replacer', function(..){...});` to set the `replacer` parameter to JSON.stringify that is used under the hood.

**UPDATE:** for pretty printing html, I don't think there is anything built into Express for that..

Comment: Hey @mscdex, this solution works perfect for pretty printing html. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you'd make this a feature of your application. You're increasing the size of your JSON payloads by adding extra spacing.

Comment: @sctskw Presumably you'd only have that `app.set()` in development mode.

Comment: I still don't think prettifying output is the job of your application. That is the job of the viewer you are using. And there are dozens of way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed - JSON in readable format, not minified.